Why is a LEAST column expression considered imprecise and not indexable?
I have a SQL Server database project:

With COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 160
With ANSI-compliant SET options:

ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, and QUOTED_IDENTIFIER all ON.
NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT is OFF
I also verified my SSMS connection-specific ANSI_NULLS is ON.



It's deployed in both Azure SQL and SQL Server 2022.
I created a table, like this:
CREATE TABLE dbo.Foobar ( 
    FooId               int          NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    DateCreated         datetime2(7)     NULL,
    DateDiscombobulated datetime2(7)     NULL,
    DatePalm            datetime2(7)     NULL,
    DateIsActuallyAFig  datetime2(7)     NULL
);

And a computed column:
ALTER TABLE dbo.Foobar ADD
    LeastDate AS LEAST(
        DateCreated,
        DateDiscombobulated,
        DatePalm,
        DateIsActuallyAFig
    ),
    GreatestDate AS GREATEST(
        DateCreated,
        DateDiscombobulated,
        DatePalm,
        DateIsActuallyAFig
    );

I want to create a nonclustered index over LeastDate and GreatestDate - ideally without making them PERSISTED columns; according to the documentation the following requirements must be met:

All function references in the computed column must have the same owner as the table.   - ✔️ No UDFs are being referenced.
The computed_column_expression must be deterministic  - ✔️ The LEAST expression has IsDeterministic = 1 according to COLUMNPROPERTY().
When the database compatibility level setting is 90, you can't create indexes on computed columns that contain [non-Unicode] expressions. - ✔️ This is not a char/varchar expression.
The computed_column_expression must be precise:

It isn't an expression of the float or real data types. - ✔️ Indeed.
It doesn't use a float or real data type in its definition. - ✔️ Indeed, it does not.
The IsPrecise property of the COLUMNPROPERTY function reports whether a computed_column_expression is precise. - ❌ IsPrecise = 0 here.


Data-type requirements: cannot evaluate to text, ntext, image - or be derived from xml or max-length types. ✔️
SET options must be: ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, and QUOTED_IDENTIFIER all ON - and NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT is OFF - ✔️


Here is the COLUMNPROPERTY query:
DECLARE @tableId int = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Foobar');

SELECT
    OBJECTPROPERTY( @tableId, 'IsAnsiNullsOn' ) AS IsAnsiNullsOn;

SELECT
    c.COLUMN_NAME,
    COLUMNPROPERTY( @tableId, c.COLUMN_NAME, 'IsDeterministic') AS IsDeterministic,
    COLUMNPROPERTY( @tableId, c.COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIndexable'    ) AS IsIndexable,
    COLUMNPROPERTY( @tableId, c.COLUMN_NAME, 'IsPrecise'      ) AS IsPrecise
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
WHERE
    c.TABLE_NAME = N'Foobar';

Results:



COLUMN_NAME
IsDeterministic
IsIndexable
IsPrecise




FooId
NULL
1
NULL


DateCreated
NULL
1
NULL


DateDiscombobulated
NULL
1
NULL


DatePalm
NULL
1
NULL


DateIsActuallyAFig
NULL
1
NULL


LeastDate
1
0
0


GreatestDate
1
0
0



It looks like it's because IsPrecise = 0, but IsPrecise should be NULL for datetime2(7) columns - the documentation says it's only NOT NULL for float/real typed-columns (I think?).

Converting the computed columns to PERSISTED allows them to be indexed, but this isn't ideal for my situation:
ALTER TABLE dbo.Foobar DROP LeastDate, GreatestDate;
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Foobar 
    ADD LeastDate AS LEAST(
        DateCreated, DateDiscombobulated, DatePalm, DateIsActuallyAFig
    ) PERSISTED,
    GreatestDate AS GREATEST(
        DateCreated, DateDiscombobulated, DatePalm, DateIsActuallyAFig
    ) PERSISTED;

Re-running the COLUMNPROPERTY query now returns:



COLUMN_NAME
IsDeterministic
IsIndexable
IsPrecise




LeastDate
1
1
0


GreatestDate
1
1
0




The reason might be because the functions invoke CLR, like FORMAT. CLR functions are defined as imprecise. I can't, however, find any thingto suggest that the functions are CLR (FORMAT is documented to use CLR).

The LEAST() and GREATEST() functions are always evaluated as imprecise when used in a computed column. The SQL engine will not recognise that all function arguments are of the same type.
There's 2 things you could try.
Use CONVERT to explicitly specify data type
ALTER TABLE dbo.Foobar ADD
    LeastDate AS CONVERT(datetime2(7), LEAST(
        CONVERT(datetime2(7), DateCreated),
        CONVERT(datetime2(7), DateDiscombobulated),
        CONVERT(datetime2(7), DatePalm),
        CONVERT(datetime2(7), DateIsActuallyAFig)
    )),
    GreatestDate AS CONVERT(datetime2(7), GREATEST(
        CONVERT(datetime2(7), DateCreated),
        CONVERT(datetime2(7), DateDiscombobulated),
        CONVERT(datetime2(7), DatePalm),
        CONVERT(datetime2(7), DateIsActuallyAFig)
    ));

Use CASE comparison
You'll need to take a different approach using CASE. From a computation overhead perspective I don't expect this will be much (if at all) different to using the functions.
ALTER TABLE dbo.Foobar ADD
    LeastDate AS CASE
                    WHEN DateCreated <= DateDiscombobulated AND DateCreated <= DatePalm AND DateCreated <= DateIsActuallyAFig THEN DateCreated
                    WHEN DateDiscombobulated <= DatePalm AND DateDiscombobulated <= DateIsActuallyAFig THEN DateDiscombobulated
                    WHEN DatePalm <= DateIsActuallyAFig THEN DatePalm
                    ELSE DateIsActuallyAFig
                 END,
    GreatestDate AS CASE
                       WHEN DateCreated >= DateDiscombobulated AND DateCreated >= DatePalm AND DateCreated >= DateIsActuallyAFig THEN DateCreated
                       WHEN DateDiscombobulated >= DatePalm AND DateDiscombobulated >= DateIsActuallyAFig THEN DateDiscombobulated
                       WHEN DatePalm >= DateIsActuallyAFig THEN DatePalm
                       ELSE DateIsActuallyAFig
                    END;

NOTE: Negating use of PERSISTED will obviously have an impact on performance, since SQL needs to maintain the index, and any updates to the compated dates will cause reevaluation of the computed column and possible index changes.

"The LEAST() and GREATEST() functions are always evaluated as imprecise when used in a computed column." - Is this documented anywhere?

I can see how using CONVERT outside of LEAST/GREATEST would work - but why would using CONVERT inside LEAST/GREATEST make a difference?

It's not documented, no. The CONVERT inside was just belts and braces. Probably not required.

I suspect that because LEAST() and GREATEST()accept and return mixed types, including imprecise types like FLOAT, the result is always considered imprecise (even when we really know it is not for a particular usage). It looks like the CONVERT() attempts didn't work, but the CASE expression does. That may be the best bad option. fiddle.

@TN T-SQL has other built-ins and syntax features that accept mixed-types without changing IsPrecise though - for example, ISNULL and IIF have IsPrecise = 1 when used with datetime arguments - weird.

@Dai Interesting. ISNULL will return a BIT, which is a precise type, so I can understand this one. Perhaps the engine is actually able to properly determine the data type of an IIF, since it only has two possible return values and types. Just a guess.

@ArchitectJamie ISNULL(x,y) , despite the name, it isn't a bool or bit-returning. function (unless x is bit, ofc).

It's worth noting that the CASE expression attempt may (will) give undesired results with NULL values. If DateIsActuallyAFig had the value NULL and none of the others do, then NULL would be returned.

RE:: " The SQL engine will not recognise that all function arguments are of the same type." - what makes you think this is the reason? Your CONVERT attempt still has the same problem. TBH I just think likely some omission when those functions were implemented w.r.t. the metadata it returns on this

@MartinSmith What I expect to be the case is that, since the return may undergo implicit type conversion, SQL doesn't even try to figure out what the return type will be. Imagine being the programmer and having to duplicate and adapt the logic from your type conversion routines just to determine whether it returns a precise type or not. You might be tempted to just stipulate that it's always considered imprecise to be on the safer side.

@ArchitectJamie - It certainly does figure out what the return type is. The computed column has a datatype (datetime2(7))

@MartinSmith Yes, this is the type returned when you run the function with real data. What I'm saying though is that the IsPrecise column property value is not calculated using actual data, and I don't believe the routines to determine the return type when the computed column is created or updated are robust enough to determine return type of LEAST and GREATEST.

I accepted this answer solely for the opening paragraph (i.e. that LEAST and GREATEST are bugged right now) - however none of the suggested workarounds work, unfortunately.

@Dai. OK. I thought someone above had some success with the CASE workaround, but if it doesn't work for you then it's not a valid workaround I guess.

@ArchitectJamie My actual table has 20+ date columns - so the CASE expression ends up horribly unergonomic

Ah, I understand. Yeah 4 columns would be somewhat comparable to the functions, but the compute cost does rise exponentially with the number of inputs.
